# How to scope belongs to many relationship appropriately

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My application has the following entities:

- `Locations`
- `Disciplines`
- `Instructors`

`Disciplines` and `Instructors` should be a many to many relationship, so in my `Discipline` model I have the following:

```php
public function instructors() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Instructor::class,
        'location_discipline_instructors',
        'discipline_id',
        'id'
    )->withPivot(['location_id']);
}
```

My `pivot` table contains the following fields:

- `location_id`
- `discipline_id`
- `instructor_id`

To get a list of disciplines with their associated instructors, I do something like this:

```php
return Discipline::whereHas('instructors', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('location_id', '=', $this->locationId);
})->with('instructors')->get();
```

Initially I thought this was exactly what I needed - and it is close, but not quite what I want. Here is a sample response I get back:

```json
{
  "disciplineId": 4,
  "discipline": "Used Tire Sales",
  "updatedBy": null,
  "instructors": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "firstname": "Jacque",
      "lastname": "Morton",
      "pivot": {
        "disciplineId": 4,
        "id": 5,
        "locationId": 27
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstname": "System",
      "lastname": "Administrator",
      "pivot": {
        "disciplineId": 4,
        "id": 1,
        "locationId": 26
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is a list of all disciplines associated with `locationId 26`, but the instructors are not being filtered by the `locationId` - notice the first instructor returned has a `locationId` of 27 instead of 26. Have I missed something obvious in the documentation? If not, how can I filter the instructors by locationId as well?

Comment: have you tried `wherePivot()` also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel With and WhereHas are 2 separate task performed from the eloquent builder and they are not really aware of each other since they are not sharing the same queries.
So try something like this:

```
return Discipline::with(['instructors' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('location_id', '=', $this->locationId);
}])
    ->whereHas('instructors', function ($query) {
        return $query->where('location_id', '=', $this->locationId);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you @Tanner - I ended up finding a solution at laracasts, but this is the correct answer